# How to select properties with specific attribute using Ndepend

Tags: ndepend

I have properties with attribute [Audit] like this

```
[Audit]
public string WorkPhone
{
     get { return workPhone; }
     set { workPhone = value; }
}
```

I need to select all such properties. But there is no predefined domain - Properties at Ndepend. And the query `from prop in Methods  where prop.HasAttribute("Audit.Audit") select prop`
returns no method matched.

So is any option to select properties with attribute exist?

Answer (score 0):

[NDepend v2023.1 now supports IProperty](https://www.ndepend.com/whatsnew#v2023-1-property-event) and you can write the code query::

```
from prop in Properties where prop.HasAttribute("Audit.Audit") select prop
```

Comment: I can't do it because of `[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Class  )]`
Why are you exclude Properties from predefined domain? It's very annoying me from 3 version and now in 4

Comment: Including properties object, and not only getter and setter, is indeed a feature we have in the pipe.

Comment: Is this still not possible?  I need to do this!

Comment: No it is not yet possible, please vote for this feature here https://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/4565818-create-an-ndepend-codemodel-iproperty-interface